# rails console command not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-console

The `rails console` command is not working on digitalocean. I have also tried `RAILS_ENV=staging bundle exec rails console`.

Is this a known issue? Experts please help me.

It just shows rails command for creating new rails application.

I am using a ubuntu 14.04 server in digitalocean.

Comment: Are you giving the command in the project directory? Looks like you didn't.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I have figured it out.

I just remove bin directory and run the command to regenerate bin again.

Running below commands solve my problem.

```
rm -r bin/*

bundle exec rake rails:update:bin
```

Comment: I was having the problem locally and this fixed it, thanks!

Comment: Save me a lot if time. Super! <3

Comment: Thanks so much. Saved me some serious pain.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are not giving the command `rails console` inside ***project directory***. You should be giving the command in the project directory.

When `rails console` is given ***outside*** the ***project directory***(see the below image)

[image]

And when the `rails console` is given ***inside*** the ***project directory***(see the below image)

[image]

Comment: I like that amber...it's like the old amber CRT color